# RDL set page break

Tags: sql-server-2008, report, rdl, page-break

I am trying to set a page break on a sub report that is acting as a cover page.

Does andybody out there know how to do this ? Right now, I stretch the height of the report to force the page break.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 (SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio), SQL Server 2008 R2.

Much appreciated !

Jeffery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the PageBreakAfter property of the subreport

More: [How to: Add a Page Break (Reporting Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156434.aspx)